# Why does adding an element in an IF block work while iterating over HashMap?

Tags: java

Why does adding an element into a HashMap work inside an `IF` block while iterating it using an iterator?

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();  
    map.put(1, 1);  
    map.put(2, 2);  
    map.put(3,3);  
      
    Iterator<Integer> it = map.keySet().iterator();  
    while(it.hasNext()) {  
        Integer key = it.next();  
        System.out.println("Map Value:" + map.get(key));  
        if (key.equals(2)) {  
            map.put(1, 4);                                 // Works, Why?
        }  
        //map.put(5, 5);                                   // ConcurrentModificationException, as expected
    }
```

Please point me to any duplicates, if any, I'll delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just updating the value inside the map for key `1` in the `if` while outside of the if you add a new key with `5` making the size of the map bigger. Therefore you are modifying the size and the iterator fails.

In general: If you want to compare why one call works and the other not, make sure you are using *exactly* the same call with the same parameters. So `map.put(1,4)` will work to outside the if.